# Como solicitar a avaliação no aplicativo android em java?

Tags: java, android

Qual a melhor forma de solicitar avaliação do app android? Ex. se o usuário optar por avaliar ele é direcionado para fazer uma resenha do app no google play.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não, normalmente, um utilizador a usar Android já está com o login no dispositivo, não terá que fazer novo login para avaliar uma aplicação.

## Solicitar avaliação da aplicação

Não existe uma "melhor forma" porque cada caso é um caso, todavia, existe um consenso de não andar a incomodar o utilizador da aplicação pois isso pode levar o mesmo a desistir de a utilizar, nem intervir junto do utilizador quando a aplicação se "porta mal".

Com isto em mente, a forma ideal tende a ser:

- Solicitar avaliação se a aplicação não anda a *crashar*;
- Solicitar após algumas utilizações para garantir que o utilizador está *viciado* e assim aumentar a probabilidade de ele vir a realizar a avaliação.

## Solução

Existe um projeto no GitHub que nos permite lidar com todas as preocupações em cima expostas:

### [AppRate](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate)

Permite ao utilizadores da aplicação avaliarem a mesma e fornece uma série de opções para personalizar a caixa de diálogo bem como o funcionamento da mesma.

#### Como instalar

Colocar o jar `AppRate` na pasta `libs` ou adicionar o `AppRate` como uma biblioteca do projeto.

#### Como usar

Instanciar o `AppRate` na `MAIN activity` da seguinte forma:

```
new AppRate(this).init();
```

#### Lidar com as preocupações que vimos em cima

- Não pedir avaliação se a aplicação "crashou":

  ```
  new AppRate(this)
    .setShowIfAppHasCrashed(false)
    .init();
  ```
- Indicar quando deve ser pedida a avaliação:

  ```
  new AppRate(this)
    .setMinDaysUntilPrompt(7)
    .setMinLaunchesUntilPrompt(20)
    .init();
  ```
- Personalizar:

  ```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setCustomTitle(myCustomTitleView)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.my_custom_icon)
    .setMessage("My custom message")
    .setPositiveButton("My custom positive button", null)
    .setNegativeButton("My custom negative button", null)
    .setNeutralButton("My custom neutral button", null);

  new AppRate(this)
    .setCustomDialog(builder)
    .init();
  ```

---

<sup>**Nota:**

Convém salientar que a votação é feita na página da aplicação, ou seja, quando o utilizador clica no botão para avaliar, vai ser direcionado para a página da aplicação a usar esta biblioteca.

Não existe forma de avaliar dentro da aplicação, a Google não permite e duvido que veja a permitir devido aos potenciais abusos e problemas dai oriundos.</sup>

Comment: muito obrigado @Zuul foi muito útil pra mim.